# Does $P(X>a|Y>a) = P(X>a)\ \forall\ a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$ imply X and Y to be independent random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can we provide a counter example where the below condition is satisfied for some $a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$ but X and Y are dependent random variables -
$$P(X>a|Y>a) = P(X>a)$$

Comment: This is the second time today I have seen a version of this question. What if $Y$ is dependent but **always** $>a$?

Comment: Can you provide a link if there's a similar question?

Comment: I think it was asked in the mathematics chat room. Not so easy to search. But consider my reasonable suggestion :-).

Comment: If $Y = X + 2$, then Y is always greater than $X$ but it does not affect $P(X > a)$. I mean $P(X > a)$ is independent of $P(Y > a)$. Am I right?

Comment: Well, you need to be careful. Ideally you want $P[Y>a] =1$.

Comment: Yes, can we show that using any value of $a$?

Comment: What copper.hat is saying is that if $a$ is such that $P(Y > a)=1$, then $P(X > a \mid Y > a) = P(X > a)$ no matter the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. So to cook up a counterexample, just choose some random variable $Y$ that does not take arbitrarily small values, and then choose $a$ appropriately.